# Lzz (Lazy C++) - #include file not found

Tags: c++, include, lazy-c++

I am trying to use Lzz to generate C++ header files from my *.cpp files.

The calling sequence is something like this:
./lzz -hx hpp -c -o out src/*.lzz

Unfortunately, it always fails saying it couldn't find any included headers, including parts of the standard library such as iostream, string and vector.

I get a bunch of error messages like these:

src/CommonIO.lzz:7:10: #include file  not found.
src/CommonIO.lzz:8:10: #include file  not found.
src/CommonIO.lzz:9:10: #include file  not found.

I know I can do give it include paths using the -I parameter:
-I /usr/local/include/c++/4.5.1

but it does not seem to help, because it starts complaining about includes from the standard library:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.5.1/string:40:10: #include file  not found.

Could it be caused by the fact that I am running the 32-bit version (binary downloaded from http://www.lazycplusplus.com/download.html) on a 64-bit system (Ubuntu 10.10)?

I have already tried to compile my own Lzz from the source, but It complains about missing rule for making libconf.a:

make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/petmal/Desktop/Downloads/lzz_2_8_2_src/gcc.opt/libs/libconf.a', needed by`/home/petmal/Desktop/Downloads/lzz_2_8_2_src/gcc.opt/lzz'.  Stop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enclose your #includes with

```
#hdr
...
#end
```

The delimited lines are copied verbatim to the header file.